# AppleScript with Pages: Can't set individual column widths?

Tags: applescript

I've tried the simplest script I can possibly come up with. Pages just won't cooperate if there are merged cells in a table:

```
 tell application "Pages"
     tell document 1
         set width of column 3 of table 1 to 55
     end tell
 end tell
```

All this does is set ALL the columns to 55. It doesn't set column 3 to 55. It works fine if there are no merged cells in the table, but not if some rows have merged cells in them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that there's a "Table Direction" button that makes my question obsolete. Nevermind!